# Wordpress everything after this slug / link

Tags: php, wordpress, post

Is there a way to create the follow in Wordpress:
Hyperlink to page: www.localhost.com/products/
**On this page there is a list with products**

If the user click on a link the browser goes for example to:
www.localhost.com/products/book-cartoon-small

The problem is both are pages I want to split up this to productlist page "IS PAGE" and product page "IS SINGLE POST"

Is there somebody who knows how to create this with a statement?

```
    $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'product'));
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

    if ( is_page('') ){ 
    ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">Go to product</a>
    <?php

    }else{// if is single post.

    echo get_the_title();
    echo the_content();   
}
    endwhile;
```

Maybe it is possible to create a if statement with everything after **products/**   to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an archive page for your products with by setting `'has_archive' => true` and creating a `archive-product.php` template file in your theme. Next add a `single-product.php` template. Do no forget to reset your permalinks after adding the archive. That should give you a start.

A turorial can be found here https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-post-types-archive-page-in-wordpress/

And do not forget to check on the wordpress stack exchange. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/